# Mysql replace part of text within Join

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to replace part of text in a join?
My unsuccessful attempt at this is as below. Thanks

```
        SELECT table1.name3
        FROM table2
        LEFT JOIN table1
        ON table2.name3 = REPLACE(table1.name4, 'this', 'that') 
        AND table2.name2 = table1.name2
        WHERE table2.f_name = 'steve'
```

Comment: why dont you do this at application side with php variable and then use that php variable in query ?

Comment: @Hytool Can you please give an example on how to do this using php

Comment: you want to replace a string in column name, right ?  in left join ??? please give me one example of original value of table1.name4 (which has 'this' string in it) .